# Use of forcing to real line to make elements countable

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, forcing

Can we use forcing techniques to force the set of elements of the real line to be countable? If not can anyone show why it is not possible?

Comment: This comment is not about forcing. If ZFC is consistent, then by the Loewenheim-Skolem Theorem it has a countable model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No and yes.

It is a theorem (of ZF) that $\mathbb{R}$ is an uncountable set.  Since forcing produces new models of ZF(C) from old ones, you cannot use forcing to produce models in which theorems of ZF(C) are false.

However...

Starting with a model $V$ of (a sufficiently large fragment of) ZFC, there is a set $\mathbb{R}^V$ in $V$ which corresponds to $V$'s version of the real numbers.  You *can* force to construct a new model $V^* \supseteq V$ of ZFC such that $$V^* \models \text{"} \mathbb{R}^V \text{ is countable."}$$  Again, $V^*$'s version of the real numbers will still be an uncountable set from $V^*$'s perspective.

Comment: Ok, so can a new model prove that real line can exist in it?

Comment: @qpr: From ZF you can construct (a set which has all of the properties we generally ascribe to) $\mathbb{R}$, so, yes, the real line (or some set which is indistinguishable from the real line without transcending the model $V$ (or $V^*$)) exists in all models of ZF.

Answer (score 4):

When we collapse the contiuum to be countable we only make the "old" real line countable. In doing so we add a lot if real numbers that weren't there before.

Internally the real numbers can never be countable, as this would contradict Cantor's theorem.